# PHP preg_replace cuts of my $subject string

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace

I was working on this project of mine when I encountered the following problem. I have a link which goes to:

`file.php?page=1&color=all&pos=all&nat=all&mine=all&tree=all`

Now, I wanted to change the color to 'gold' so I looked around on Google and found this php function called `preg_replace()`. So I implemented it in my code like this:

`$pre='?page=1&color=all&pos=all&nat=all&mine=all&tree=all';
preg_replace('/color=(.*)&/', 'color=gold&', $pre);`

For some reason my output is `?page=1&color=gold&tree=all` so it seems that it cut of the middle of the code somehow.

This is the link I expect as my output: `?page=1&color=gold&pos=all&nat=all&mine=all&tree=all`

Can anybody tell me what it is I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular Expressions (regex) are greedy. You said "find color=" and then "get as much as you can until you see a &". What you want is "get as much as you can as long as it is not a &". That would be:

```
preg_replace('/color=[^&]*/','color=gold',$pre);
```

The [^&] means "anything except &". Also - you aren't using the match, so you don't need the parenthesis.

Comment: Wow dude thanks! Didn't thought about that! Perfect solution :)

Comment: Mikelo, if it worked for you, accept it as the answer.

Comment: Yeah I know but it said I had to wait 7 min xD